# Why does escaping of # disappear when read from an array?

Tags: perl

I have a string,

```
my $element="abc#$def"
```

I escape # using,

```
 $element=~s/#/\\#/g;
```

It is printed as: `abc\#$def`, which is perfect.

Next part of the code is:

```
push(@arr,$element);
foreach $val (@arr)
{
 print $val;
}
```

And the value printed within the foreach loop is: `abc#$def`.

Why is `#` not escaped here? And how can I retain the escaping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not quite showing us everything.  To get your claimed result, I had to create the variable `$def` initialized as shown below.  But, when I do that, I get the result you expect, not the result you show.

```
$ cat xx.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $def = '$def';
my $element = "abc#$def";

$element =~ s/#/\\#/g;

print "$element\n";

my @arr;

push(@arr, $element);
foreach my $val (@arr)
{
    print $val;
    print "\n";
}

$ perl xx.pl
abc\#$def
abc\#$def
$
```

This was tested with Perl 5.14.1 on MacOS X 10.6.8, but I don't think the behaviour would vary with any other version of Perl 5.

Given this, can you update your question to show a script similar to mine (in particular, with both `use strict;` and `use warnings;`) but which produces the result you show?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I had missed "use strict",  wonder if that was the reason. Working as needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

With something like this:

```
$element=~s/#/\\#/g;
```

You have to escape the `\`

**Edit**

this code works on my machine as you expect:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $element='abc#$def';
my @arr;
$element=~s/#/\\#/g;

print $element."\n";

push(@arr,$element);
foreach my $val (@arr)
{
 print $val;
}
```

Comment: You mean, $element=~s/#/\\\#/g;  right? Even this shows the same behaviour.

Comment: hmm...no, I meant exactly what is in your code also, because at first it looked like you had a single `\\` character in your replace expression

Comment: Ok.. It does get escaped. But behaviour changes when it is read from an array as I have explained.

Comment: When I altered the formatting from 'running text' to code, there were two backslashes in the text of the question.  I'm not sure whether @Mini was handling that correctly.  Mostly what I did was add blank lines after the running text to let the code stand out as code - the exception, of course, is the output embedded in with running text.  If need be, Mini can update the code to reflect what is in the program causing trouble; I've already asked for an executable example.

Comment: @Mini - I think the lack of `use strict` and `use warnings` is giving you side effects from other parts of the code